# Identify Data Vectors with New Attributes and/or Values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am setting up a classification system using scikit-learn.  After training a classifier I would like to save it for reuse along with the necessary transforms such as the DictVectorizer.

I am looking for a way to filter the incoming stream of unclassified data that will feed into the feature transforms and classifier.  Ideally, I would like to remove and flag vectors that contain new values for categorical attributes and/or altogether new attributes.

I have used the DictVectorizer.restrict() method to filter input data but this only results in the vectorizer filtering new attributes and zeroing new values, where I would also like to put aside inconsistent data.  Is there an easy way to pull out rows with values and attribute that were not in the initial data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with anything built into scikit-learn, as removing rows is something that is not easily done in the current API.
It should be quite easy to write a custom function / class that does that based on the output of DictVectorizer.

Comment: Thank you. It would have been nice to have but will also be very easy to do as preprocessing with Pandas.